# Fire validation when focus out from input in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-validation, angular4-forms

Email validation is being fired as we keep typing in textbox. I want this validation to be fired when user focuses out of the textbox

Below is my code:

```
<input class="form-control" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$"
 name="Email" type="email" [(ngModel)]="model.Email" #Email="ngModel" required>

<div class="red" *ngIf="Email.errors && (Email.dirty || Email.touched)">
     <div [hidden]="!Email.errors.pattern">
         Please enter a valid email.
     </div>
</div>
```

Please suggest me how can I achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you also want to remove validation while typing?

Comment: I see that your are using, model driven form here. Try using reactive form module. There you can call validation manually on blur or focus.

Comment: `Template driven forum` is used in my whole application . is reactive form module is only way of achieve this?

Comment: yes I also want to remove validation while typing

Comment: going by the link - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7113 provided by @Sam in answer below, it seems all you can do is to handle when you show the message and not the validation call (especially with Template Driven Form)

Comment: I switched from template driven to reactive forms in a large application and it wasn't too difficult to do.

Comment: try this for managing your messages: `<div class="validation-message" *ngIf="form.controls['xxx'].isValid && isIdle">`

Got this from the link mentioned above

Answer (score 19):

Starting with the version 6+ form field validation can be set via `updateOn` property.

With template-driven forms:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
```

With reactive forms:

```
new FormControl('', {updateOn: 'blur'});
```

And if you have validators set:

```
new FormControl('', {validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email], updateOn: 'blur'})
```

> Source: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#note-on-performance

Answer (score 3):

if you are using `Angular` you can call in this way

```
<input type="text" id="sometext" (focusout)="myFunction()">
```

otherwise, you can use

```
<input type="text" id="sometext" onfocusout="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be possible in version 5, which is not released yet.

See: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7113

In the meantime:

```
<input class="form-control" formControlName="userName" placeholder="User Name" type="text" (blur)="checkUserExists()"/>
<div class="alert-danger" *ngIf="userName.invalid && userName.touched">
  <div *ngIf="userName.hasError('required')">User Name is required</div>
  <div *ngIf="userName.hasError('userExists')">{{userName.errors.userExists}}</div>
</div>

checkUserExists() {
    if (this.userName.value) {
      this.regServ.userNameExists(this.userName.value)
      .subscribe((exists) => {
        if (exists) {
          this.userName.setErrors({ userExists: `User Name "${this.userName.value}" already exists` });
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: hey sam is this feature available yet in angular 5/6.? if yes please can you edit the answer and show how to do it.